# How to pass current date to a curl query and add 5 hours to it

Tags: linux, date, curl, yaml

Please see curl below. I am getting the current time for "startsAt". I am then adding 5 hours to that time for "endsAt". However not sure if my syntax for "endsAt" is correct since it keeps failing. Would I need to first put the results of the first timeframe into a variable and then add the 3 hours to it?

```
curl 'http://test.com' -d '{
      "matchers": [
      {
         "name": "test",
         "value": "test",
         "isRegex": true
      }
       ],
        "startsAt": "'"$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")"'", 
        "endsAt": "'"$(date -d '+ 3 hours'  +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")"'", 
        "createdBy": "test",
        "comment": "test",
        "status": {
        "state": "active"
      }}'
```

StartsAt works as intended.

Comment: A [mcve] would help... if `date` and its calculation is the problem, get rid of all the json and curl stuff. Which then makes the question just about using some unix tools, not really about programming, so it would fit better on [unix.se]. That said, your `date -d ...` (9.1, GNU coreutils) works as expected for me.

Comment: I'm getting an error stating "end time cant be in the past"

Comment: since it is set to zulu time, it worked after adding 7 hours to it

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. Glad you solved your problem.